# How to retain Javascript state on page change

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have an accordion style navigation list set up so that when categories are clicked it opens up to show sub-categories that link to pages.

What I would like to do is have the accordion navigation list keep it's open or closed state when the new page opens.

I've gathered that cookies work to retain the state on refresh, but how do I retain the state when a different page is visited? All the pages have the same accordion navigation list.

Comment: Hey Rob, are you using an existing maybe open source accordion library, maybe if you provide that we can provide you with a code sample of the solution.

Comment: I am using a jquery plug-in I found here, http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2010/02/27/yup_yet_another_jquery_accordi The site I am working on can be seen here http://robfenwick.com/avrent3/ The only link that is active so far is Sound/Audio Systems => PA Systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, it uses the accordian plug-in found here, http://www.i-marco.nl/weblog/archive/2010/02/27/yup_yet_another_jquery_accordi and the jquery cookie.js plug-in

I added id's to the header anchor tages in the HTNL mark-up like so,

```
 <li>
        <a id="m1" class="label" href="#">Sound/Audio Systems</a>
        <ul class="acitem">
            <li><a href="products.php?sub_cat=PA_Systems">PA Systems</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Loudspeakers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Microphones </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">DJ Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sound Processing Equipment</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

And modified the accordian.js code, I added the lines beginning with $.cookie, and the If statement in the document.ready funciton.

```
jQuery.fn.initMenu = function() {  
return this.each(function(){
    var theMenu = $(this).get(0);
    $('.acitem', this).hide();
    $('li.expand > .acitem', this).show();
    $('li.expand > .acitem', this).prev().addClass('active'),
    currentID = "";
    $('li a', this).click(
        function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var theElement = $(this).next();
            var parent = this.parentNode.parentNode;
            if($(parent).hasClass('noaccordion')) {
                if(theElement[0] === undefined) {
                    window.location.href = this.href;
                }
                $(theElement).slideToggle('normal', function() {
                    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                        $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                        currentID = $(this).prev().attr('id');
                        $.cookie('menustate', currentID, {expires: 2, path: '/'});
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                        $.cookie('menustate', null, {expires: 2, path: '/'});
                    }    
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && theElement.is(':visible')) {
                    if($(parent).hasClass('collapsible')) {
                        $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', 
                        function() {
                            $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                            $.cookie('menustate', null, {expires: 2, path: '/'});
                        }
                    );
                    return false;  
                }
                return false;
            }
            if(theElement.hasClass('acitem') && !theElement.is(':visible')) {         
                $('.acitem:visible', parent).first().slideUp('normal', function() {
                    $(this).prev().removeClass('active');
                    $.cookie('menustate', null, {expires: 2, path: '/'});
                });
                theElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
                    $(this).prev().addClass('active');
                    currentID = $(this).prev().attr('id');
                    $.cookie('menustate', currentID, {expires: 2, path: '/'});
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    );
});

};



$(document).ready(function() {
$('.menu').initMenu();$('#side-navigation_frame').show();
if ($.cookie('menustate')) {
    var anchor = "",
        elementID = $.cookie('menustate');
    anchor = document.getElementById(elementID);
    $(anchor).addClass('active');
    $(anchor).next().show();

}
});
```

It works nicely, not bad for a beginner, thanks for all the advise.

Rob Fenwick

Answer (score 2):

Try [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).  Store the state of the tabs on page unload, restore the state on the page load event.

Comment: @Xander If [even IE8 supports it](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) then it's probably not much of a problem.  The 1-3% of users still on IE6/7 don't get the state of their tabs restored will it be a big issue?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies "retain state" across the full path and domain for which they are specified. So if you can get them to work for just one page, you should have them work automatically on all pages of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use cookies, you just have to make sure they're not specific to the one page. For example:

```
document.cookie = 'openitem=5; expires=somedate; path=/';
```

will be accessible to all pages on the site. [More about cookies.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I took a look at the library you are using, it's a decent library and all but you might find it easier to find solutions to your problems if you use a more standard library like jQuery UI, it has an accordion control http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/ and like I mentioned there are so many people using it that the answer to most problems can be found.

But like I mentioned I did take a look at your library. As others have mentioned you would use a cookie to store the value. This library supports 'pre expanding' a particular section of the accordian, to do that you would add the expand class to the element. You can either do that server side or you can do it using JavaScript before initMenu() is called.

The other less elegant option is to trigger the click event on the anchor tag after the call to initMenu. Finally you can use jQuery's show() to show expand the section without animation.

The first thing you have to do is find out which section was clicked on, then you would store that sections name in a cookie. On page load you would get that value and expand the appropriate according section. This is what the code should kinda look like - note this is psuedo code and you have fill in the appropriate parts.

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu.collapsible .label").click(function() {
       var accordianSection = $(this).text();
       rememberSection(accordianSection);
    });

    var section = recallSection();
    if(section !== undefined) {
        expandSection(section);
    }
});
```

The expandSection function can look something like this:

```
var sectionLink = $(".menu.collapsible .label").filter(function() { 
    return $(this).text() == section;
});
sectionLink.trigger('click');
```

Comment: I took your advice and I am now using the ui accordion, the only solution I found for setting a cookie is here http://www.mikecentola.com/blog/2009/05/31/saving-state-with-the-jquery-accordion-menu/

Comment: After spending serveral hours getting the ui accordion to work the same and have the same styling as the other one I was using, and a few more hours getting the cookie to sort of work it's still buggy. The new version is here. http://robfenwick.com/avrent4/ Do you know of any other solutions for the ui accordion?

Comment: That link didn't work. Maybe you can set it up on jsFiddle that way the people here can try out different solutions. Have you tried this: http://www.mikecentola.com/blog/2009/05/31/saving-state-with-the-jquery-accordion-menu/